# Pandas: sum if columns values coincides

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do an, apparently, simple operation in python:

I have some datasets, say 6, and I want to sum the values of one column if the values of the other two columns coincides. After that, I want to divide the values of the column which has been summed by the number of datasets I have, in this case, 6 (i.e. Calculate the arithmetic mean). Also I want to sum 0 if the values of the other columns doesn't coincide.

I write down here two dataframes, as example:

`Code1    Code2   Distance
0   15.0    15.0    2
1   15.0    60.0    3
2   15.0    69.0    2
3   15.0    434.0   1
4   15.0    842.0   0`

`Code1    Code2   Distance
0   14.0    15.0    4
1   14.0    60.0    7
2   15.0    15.0    0
3   15.0    60.0    1
4   15.0    69.0    9`

The first column is the df.index column. Then , I want to sum 'Distance' column only if 'Code1' and 'Code2' columns coincide. In this case the desired output would be something like:

`Code1     Code2   Distance
0   14.0    15.0    2
1   14.0    60.0    3.5
2   15.0    15.0    1
3   15.0    60.0    2
4   15.0    69.0    5.5
5   15.0    434.0   0.5
6   15.0    842.0   0`

I've tried to do this using conditionals, but for more than two df is really hard to do. Is there any method in Pandas to do it faster?

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Could your `Code1` and `Code2` be the same in one dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to add the values of the Distance col if Code1 AND Code2 match, between each other? between df's? indipendent of index? Also, if you have N DataFrames all with the same columns why can't you just make a big df with all the data and use something like sum col where condition?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, yes, could be the same.

Comment: @nico, yes, independent of index. The problem of doing this is that I actually have 94 dataframes, not two and I think it could be slow... But good point, I'll try.

Comment: @GonzaloDonoso: I usually concatenate a bunch (300-500) of individual sessions (i.e. df's) with several hundred trials each (i.e. lines) and ~100 columns. I just add a column with the session_name so I can keep track of what data comes from when and where. It's not that slow, if it starts being a problem for some analysis I have a preprocessed full DataFrame with all my data, its much faster loading 1 big df than a bunch of them and concatenating them. Give it a try and tell me how it goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all your data frames in a list and then use `reduce` to either `append` or `merge` them all.
Take a look at reduce [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).

First, below some functions are defined for sample data generation.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

# GENERATE DATA
# Code 1 between 13 and 15
def generate_code_1(n):
    return np.floor(np.random.rand(n,1) * 3 + 13)

# Code 2 between 1 and 1000
def generate_code_2(n):
    return np.floor(np.random.rand(n,1) * 1000) + 1

# Distance between 0 and 9
def generate_distance(n):
    return np.floor(np.random.rand(n,1) * 10)

# Generate a data frame as hstack of 3 arrays
def generate_data_frame(n):
    data = np.hstack([
         generate_code_1(n)
        ,generate_code_2(n)
        ,generate_distance(n)
    ])
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Code 1', 'Code 2', 'Distance'])
    # Remove possible duplications of Code 1 and Code 2. Take smallest distance in case of duplications.
    # Duplications will break merge method however will not break append method
    df = df.groupby(['Code 1', 'Code 2'], as_index=False)
    df = df.aggregate(np.min)
    return df

# Generate n data frames each with m rows in a list
def generate_data_frames(n, m, with_count=False):
    df_list = []
    for k in range(0, n):
        df = generate_data_frame(m)
        # Add count column, needed for merge method to keep track of how many cases we have seen
        if with_count:
            df['Count'] = 1
        df_list.append(df)
    return df_list
```

Append method (faster, shorter, nicer)

```
df_list = generate_data_frames(94, 5)

# Append all data frames together using reduce
df_append = reduce(lambda df_1, df_2 : df_1.append(df_2), df_list)

# Aggregate by Code 1 and Code 2
df_append_grouped = df_append.groupby(['Code 1', 'Code 2'], as_index=False)
df_append_result = df_append_grouped.aggregate(np.mean)
df_append_result
```

Merge method

```
df_list = generate_data_frames(94, 5, with_count=True)

# Function to be passed to reduce. Merge 2 data frames and update Distance and Count
def merge_dfs(df_1, df_2):
    df = pandas.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['Code 1', 'Code 2'], how='outer', suffixes=('', '_y'))
    df = df.fillna(0)
    df['Distance'] = df['Distance'] + df['Distance_y']
    df['Count'] = df['Count'] + df['Count_y']
    del df['Distance_y']
    del df['Count_y']
    return df

# Use reduce to apply merge over the list of data frames
df_merge_result = reduce(merge_dfs, df_list)

# Replace distance with its mean and drop Count
df_merge_result['Distance'] = df_merge_result['Distance'] / df_merge_result['Count']
del df_merge_result['Count']
df_merge_result
```